# Should I use "C'est" or "Il est" or "Il fait"?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Would

> It is night.

be

> **C'est** nuit.

or

> **Il est** nuit.

or

> **Il fait** nuit.

or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can say :

- *Il fait nuit.*
- *C'est la nuit.*

The other two aren't correct.

Comment: Why not just "*C'est nuit*"? Wouldn't the "*la*" make it "*It is the night*"?

Comment: Cases where French does not use the definite article (−> *le, la, les* ) are rare. A lot rarer then in English. In *it's night* you don't use the definite article in English because here *night* is an abstract noun. In French you have to use the definite article in front of *night* in that case.  
We might find a noun without an article in ready made phrases (*jour et nuit* par exemple) or to convey a special effect.  
In general don't translate literally from one language to another, it rarely works !

Answer (score 10):

The correct translation of "It's night." is "Il fait nuit."
When you speak about the weather or the sky, you always say "Il fait".

> Il fait nuit. (It's night.)
>
> Il fait jour. (It's day.)
>
> Il fait beau. (The weather is good.)
>
> Il fait moche. (The weather is bad.)
>
> Il fait froid. (It's cold.)
>
> Il fait chaud. (It's hot.)
>
> Il fait sombre (The weather is dark. )
>
> Il fait clair. (The weather is bright. )