# When to use “Ils sont”, “ces sont” or “ce sont”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, déterminants

If for example I want to say "They are children", I would've thought one would use the phrase:

> Ils sont des enfants.

... or even:

> Ces  sont des enfants.

However I think the correct way to say it is:

> Ce sont des enfants.

But why is this?  Isn't *ce* to be used with singular nouns, not plural?  And why not *ils*?  How can you know where you should use *ce* in sentences like this, and when to use *ils*?

Comment: De ce que j'en sais, ces liens peuvent vous servir et être reliés: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6317/what-is-the-difference-between-cest-and-il-est, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6779/when-to-use-il-est-tard-vs-cest-tard, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/emploi-de-ce-comme-pronom-impersonnel, http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1614/should-i-use-cest-or-il-est-or-il-fait.

Comment: First of all : *ces sont* is NOT French.

Comment: jesus, that last one was SUPER helpful. wow.

Comment: dude i have the same question, and nothing on here is clearing it up. apparently, even though "ces" is for plural nouns like "des enfants", the french at some point decided that when it's "sont" they wanna use the "ce" just cause. It seems like it's just by convention. Everytime I see "sont" and I wanna say "these are" I'll just use "ce". even though "ces" does make more sense. *shrugs*

Comment: FOUND SOMETHING! It's more or less what I assumed. It's just idiom stuff. No rhyme, no reason. Just how it's done. This will help: https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/presentatives/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way to say it is:

> Ce sont des enfants.

This is called a ***tour présentatif*** : *Utilisation du pronom neutre **ce** suivi du verbe être accordé en nombre avec « des enfants ».*

You can get more informations here: [Grammaire française](http://books.google.fr/books?id=U31jJqXJak0C&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=le%20%22tour%20presentatif%22%20%22Ce%20sont%22&source=bl&ots=zXqvZpre_n&sig=gh4p9B7iW9lBkJ2WvJVelQpj8mM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nnpkUY3PK4PJhAeq54CIDQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=le%20%22tour%20presentatif%22%20%22Ce%20sont%22&f=false) by M. Breckx Ed. De Boeck, 1996, on google books (section 2.1.2.3 “La phrase à présentatif”). They explain it using “Ce sont les voisins”.

**Notes:** *Ces sont des enfants* is incorrect, and *Ils sont des enfants* sounds weird.

---

The reference seems not to be available to everyone. Here is a version of what is said:

> **2.1.2.3 La phrase à présentatif**
>
> Sur le plan grammatical, la phrase à présentatif se traduit selon
>   trois modèles différents:
>
> - *C'est…*, *ce sont…*
> - *Il y a…*
> - *Voici-Voilà…*
>
> **C'est…, ce sont…** Cette tournure présentative se construit avec un démonstratif plus le verbe *être*.
>
> Le verbe ne varie pas en personne mais peut varier en nombre en en temps. L'accord se fait soit
>   avec la suite du verbe, soit avec **ce** :
>
> - *C'est mon ami. – C'est les pigeons qui s'envolent.* (registre familier)
> - *Ce seraient de belles vacances.*

Il est préférable de placer le verbe au pluriel:

> - *C'est les voisins.* (oral, familier)
> - *Ce sont les voisins.* (écrit ou oral)

Exception, la phrase nominale :

> C'est nous, c'est eux.

Dans la phrase « *C'est du thé anglais* », la suite du verbe, obligatoire, s'appelle *le complément du présentatif*.

Comment: Additionnaly, I would translate `ce sont des enfants` by `these are childrens`, but don't take my word for it, my english is not very god.

Comment: Je crois que si l'on utilise la phrase "ce sont des enfants" à suivre une phrase comme "Ne te fâcher pas avec eux", la traduction pourrait bien être "Don't get angry/mad with them, they are just children". "Childrens" n'est jamais correcte.

Comment: Paola, I agree  with your translation, it looks good. Also, thanks for the correction of `children`.

Comment: @Jean I'm still not quite sure when you are meant to use the *présentatif*.  Is it basically any time you would use the verb *be* in a simple English sentence, like *x is y*, *x was y*, or *x will be y*?

Comment: When to use the présentatif? This is a hard one. Well, I think it is mainly used to put focus on the word `enfants`. Anyway, amongst the three sentences in your question, it is the only one that is correct. There is also [this webpage](http://cloud.lib.wfu.edu/wiki/modernfrench/index.php/Les_structures_à_présentatif) that aims at presenting `les structures à présentatif`, but the (obviously) translated text is not that good. And there are some additional explanations [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/53680880/248/Les-structures-a-presentatif), if you can access it.

Comment: would have appreciated the copy pasted material to also be translated in english since i am a french learner. am I in the wrong place? Imma check is there isn't a french learner's stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

> Ces sont des enfants.

This is an incorrect!

In a french book for example, you would ONLY find:

> Ce sont des enfants

In colloquial, familiar language:

> C'est des enfants

Comment: " *c'est des* " or " *ce sont des* " is 100% equivalent and acceptable. Though " *Ces sont* " is never seen and never to be seen.

Comment: @zmo *C'est des* is actually grammatically incorrect. The proper way is *Ce sont*.

Comment: @Sifu "C'est des" is not grammatically incorrect. One might even argue "Ce sont" is dubious as "Ce" is singular so shouldn't be followed by a plural. There are well known cases where "Ce sont" is not idiomatic, like "C'est dix Euros" (not "Ce sont dix Euros") or "C'est nous !" (not "Ce sont nous!").

Comment: @Sifu you're actually wrong, I had an argument with a friend a few years ago, that end up checking in a grammar book… And result was that both are right. As far as I remember, the reason being that the object pointed by "ce" being unknown before according the verb, when the object is plural, the subject can be considered either singular or plurar. So in the end, it's what jlliagre says, the "c'est" being idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

"Ce sont des enfants" is of course is right and not "Ces sont des enfants" as the right form of the "tour présentatif."  But I would suggest that "ils sont des enfants" can also be right in situations where there is a clear antecedent.

Comment: "Ils sont des enfants" is very non-idiomatic. You might say "Ils sont petits" or "ils sont encore jeunes" but "des" implies "ce".

Comment: @jilliagre I'm wondering about this... what about "ils ont beau être des militaires, ils sont des enfants aussi."?  In a phrase of this kind, I'm suggesting that the choice of "ce" or "ils"/"elles" depends on the grammatical context and desired emphasis, and that it's not really satisfactory to say "ils sont" is always wrong...

Comment: @mikerodent "Ils sont des enfants aussi." sounds very odd. That should be "Ils sont aussi des enfants." but what is really idomatic is "Ils ont beau être (des) militaires, ce sont aussi des enfants."

Comment: what an unhelpful answer. you think the person who asked this knows what "tour presentatif whatever" is ?