# What is the difference between “c'est” and “il est”?

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-impersonnels

Both of these phrases mean "it is" or "this is," so what is the difference between them? When should one be used over the other?

Answer (score 8):

*Il est* can either be designating someone (therefore meaning “*he* is”, rather than “*it* is”, as is *c'est*), or on the contrary be a construct in which there is no subject (as in *Il est tard*, or *Il est possible que …*, etc.).

In the latter cases, you can distinguish the cases when *c'est* refers to a neutral subject (“it is”, really ; e.g. *c'est tard* will mean “this event is late”) from the cases when there really is no subject (“it rains”).

I can't think of any case where “this is” would be the translation of “*il est*” ; maybe your question is all about “*ça / il*” being the translation of “it / he”.

Answer (score 3):

When this applies to a person (masculine), 'il est' is the only option.

When this applies to a concept / idea where there can be a confusion with a person, 'c'est ' is the correct choice: 'c'est malheureux' and 'il est malheureux' do have different meanings, and can lead to confusion, when one is talking\writing about a person.

Out of this ambiguitous situation, 'c'est' and 'il est' belong to different levels of language: 'c'est' is perceived as more popular, and does not require further information. 'il est' is perceived as more sophisticated, and might need some further information:

- 'c'est malheureux' \ 'il est malheureux' : 1st option applies to an idea, a situation, 2nd to a person.
- 'c'est tard' \ 'il est tard' are strictly equivalent in terms of meaning
- 'c'est malheureux' \ 'il est malheureux *que ...*' apply both to an idea, but the 2nd option will require additional information. It is still possible to say\write 'c'est malheureux *que ...*' but this would definitely be considered as a poor wording.

Comment: When this applies to a person, *il est* is not necessarily the only option or even an option at all: *C'est un dentiste/Il est dentiste*, *C'est un idiot/Il est idiot*, *C'est le président/Il est président*, *C'est mon frère*...

Answer (score 1):

Question de syntaxe, réponse simplifiée.  L'usage est souvent plus compliqué. English to follow bellow. Formulaire :

**C'est + un + nom**

**Il est + adjectif**

On emploie **c'est** et **ce sont** (pronom impersonnel *ce* + le verbe *être* conjugué) dans une phrase dont l'attribut du sujet (le complément) -- **un nom** -- est modifié par un déterminant, un article ou un adjectif possessif : l'article indéfini (**un, une, des**), l'article défini (**le, la, l', les**), l'adjectif possessif (**mon, ma, mes...leur, leurs**) ou un adjectif qui le modifie aussi.  L'accord des adjectifs ne change pas.

Par exemple, pour répondre à la question « Qu'est-ce que c'est ? » ou « Qui est-ce ? »

- C'est un ami.  C'est un ancien ami.
- C'est une montre.  C'est une montre suisse.
- Ce sont des photos.  Ce sont des photos originales.

Par contre, on emploie **il est, elle est, ils sont, elles sont** (pronom personnel 3è personne + le verbe *être* conjugué) avec des adjectifs.

- Il est sympa. (mon ancien ami)
- Elle est belle. (sa montre suisse)
- Elles sont originales. (ses photos)

Bien sûr il y a des usages plus générales de **c'est** et **ce sont**, c'est normal.  C'est comme ça. C'est le temps que tu as perdu pour ta rose qui fait ta rose si importante.   Ce n'est pas le moment.

**Ce** est aussi employé quand le verbe être est suivi d'un nom propre, d'un pronom disjonctif ou d'un supérlatif.

- C'est Mme Lemai.
- C'est moi.
- C'est le plus beau.

---

This is a syntax question, and there is a formula derived from the grammar.  Usage varies, but simply put, a formula:

**C'est + un + noun**

**Il est + adjective**

Use **c'est** and **ce sont** (impersonal pronoun *ce* + *être* conjugated) when the subject complement -- **a noun** -- is modified by a determiner, often an article or possessive adjective or generally when that noun is also modified by an adjective:

- l'article indéfini (**un, une, des**)
- l'article défini (**le, la, l', les**)
- l'adjectif possessif (**mon, ma, mes...leur, leurs**).

For example, to answer the question « Qu'est-ce que c'est ? » ou « Qui est-ce ? »

- C'est un ami.  C'est un ancien ami. "He's a friend.  He's an old friend." (Or "This is/That's a friend.")
- C'est une montre.  C'est une montre suisse. "It's a watch. It's a Swiss watch."
- Ce sont des photos.  Ce sont des photos originales. "These/those/they are photos/pictures.  They're the original photos."

Otherwise, use **il est, elle est, ils sont, elles sont** (3rd person personal pronoun + *être* conjugated) with adjectives.

- Il est sympa. (mon ancien ami) "He's nice." (my old friend)
- Elle est belle. (sa montre suisse) "It's lovely." (his Swiss watch)
- Elles sont originales. (ses photos) "They are (the) original(s)." (his pictures)

There are many more usages of **c'est** et **ce sont**, which is part of language:  C'est normal.  C'est comme ça. C'est le temps que tu as perdu pour ta rose qui fait ta rose si importante.   Ce n'est pas le moment.

**Ce** is also used with être when followed by a proper noun, a disjunctive/tonic pronoun, or a superlative. It can be translated as "it is/it's", "this is," or "that is/that's" depending on context.

- C'est Mme Lemai.
- C'est moi.
- C'est le plus beau.

Voir :

Grammaire française, Ollivier et Beaudoin

["Il est avocat" vs "C'est un avocat" ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16619/il-est-avocat-vs-cest-un-avocat?rq=1)  Exceptions avec un nom de profession ou de nationalité

[When to use c'est or il/elle est when describing the shapes of objects?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16510/when-to-use-cest-or-il-elle-est-when-describing-the-shapes-of-objects?rq=1)

Comment: appreciate the translation