# Article devant un nom de métier

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

Normalement, on ne met pas d'article devant un nom de métier.

> Je suis professeur. Je suis boulanger.

Mais imaginons le dialogue suivant :

> A : Es-tu boulanger ?
>
> B : Non, je suis (**un**) maçon.

Dans ce cas, faut-il mettre l'article indéfini devant *maçon*, ceci parce que la phrase de B sous-entend *Non, je ne suis pas (**un**) boulanger, je suis (**un**) maçon* ?

Comment: Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16619/il-est-avocat-vs-cest-un-avocat

Comment: @jlliagre Merci beaucoup pour le lien.

Comment: @jlliagre Pourquoi as-tu mis un "y" dans "d'article" et "emphasized text" dans la 4ème ligne ? Es-tu sûr que la question soit meilleure ainsi ?

Comment: ***D'oh!*** Leçon n° 1: ne jamais sous estimer ce que peut faire un smartphone seul dans une poche...  :-)

Answer (score 6):

Je ne vois pas de nécessité d'ajouter un article indéfini, ni dans un cas, ni dans l'autre :

> A : Es-tu boulanger ?
> B : Non, je suis maçon.
> A : Mais on m'a bien dit que tu étais un boulanger…
> B : Oui, c'est mon nom de famille, je suis bien un Boulanger. Et toi ?
> A : Oh, pardon ! C'est amusant, car moi qui suis boulanger, je suis un Masson.

Évidemment, à l'écrit, tout de suite, ça saute aux yeux. À l'oral, par contre, la différence vient de l'article ; mais ça reste une source de quiproquos pour les inattentifs :-). Une petite remarque : je n'ai jamais rencontré la graphie Maçon en nom de famille, et fr.Wikipédia n'en cite aucun.

NB: la forme « **je suis un·e** /*nomDeFamille*/ » n'est typiquement utilisé que dans un contexte de zones géographiques où ces noms de famille sont courants, ce qui n'est pas rare dans les villages en régions rurales. Sinon, on utilisera plutôt le classique « **je m'appelle** ».

En fait, on retrouve la même nuance qu'entre « *je suis française* » et « *je suis **une** française* », ou leur variante masculine : la première forme est un qualificatif, alors que la seconde réfère incidemment à un groupe spécifique, et éventuellement insiste sur l'appartenance à ce groupe.

Du coup, on peut très bien imaginer une situation où l'article indéfini prend sens devant un nom de métier. Par exemple :
  « *Je suis boulanger. Mais ne vous méprenez pas, je ne suis pas juste un pétrisseur et un cuiseur. Nous, les boulangers, avons bien plus en tête qu'une simple recette d'assemblage et de manipulation qu'on reproduirait chaque jour, chaque nuit. Selon le météo, selon la saison, et selon les envies du moment de la clientèle, nous savons composer. C'est pour ça que n'importe quelle échoppe qui vend /du pain/, ne peut pas marquer « boulangerie » sur sa vitrine ; boulanger est un titre, et un métier, reconnu : oui, je suis bien un boulanger.* »

Comment: Bienvenu chez FSE. Bravo pour ta réponse (chez FSE on se tutoie:-)!).

Comment: Je vous remercie pour votre réponse.

Comment: @Oreste chez FSE on se tutoie:-)! De plus, il n'y pas besoin de saluer (ce n'est pas un forum) ni de remercier. L'OP montre son appréciation par le vote positif et la sélection d'une réponse comme la réponse préférée (le cas échéant).

Comment: @Dimitris Pour ma part, je préférerais le vouvoyement si on n'a pas élevé les cochons ensemble. En outre, une certaine liberté est bénéfique à tout le monde. Mais quoi qu'il en soit, vous pouvez voir la réponse de l'un des modérateurs sur ce sujet "Chez Cosette" il y a une semaine.

Comment: @Oreste On a la liberté, certes. Continuez le vouvoiement (et pas vouvoyement:-)!) si vous le désirez. Mais, ne sentez-vous pas agressé s'il y a quelqu'un qui s'addresse à vous en se tutoyant:-)!

Comment: @Dimitris Ah, non :) Mais je peux te tutoyer si tu le veux. Là,je m'adressais à ELw que je ne "connais" pas tant que ça pour l'instant.

Comment: @Oreste Très bien:-)! BTW, tu as un super prénom ; je crois que tu sais qu'Oreste provient de la mythologie grecque (je suis grec, d'où le commentaire).

Comment: @Oreste Diable ! Mais je suis un cochon, d'abord. Sinon, où vous aurais-je tutoyé·e ? J'ai beau relire ma réponse, les seuls "tu", "te" ou "toi" que j'ai usagés, sont soit des syllabes de mots, soit au sein de la conversation construite qui sert d'exemple, en continuité avec le vôtre. Certes, si j'eus dû m'adresser à vous comme je le fais actuellement, cela m'eût été violence, après plus d'une demi-siècle de tutoiement professionnel ; on ne se remet en cause que difficilement. Mais dans ce genre de réponse, on interpèle rarement le questionnant, au contraire des échanges en petits commentaires

Comment: @Oreste /suite…/ (aie ! je suis trop bavard ; la limite m'a frappé juste avant mes grognements finaux…). Et donc :
Au plaisir de vous lire. Bien le bonjour amical chez vous ! -- ÉLw

Comment: Je n'ai pas trop compris.Tu (vous ?) préfère le tutoiement ? Très bien. Je disais seulement qu'en cas de doute, je crois que le vouvoiement est plus prudent, certains n'aiment pas le tutoiement.

Comment: En effet, moi non plus, je ne trouve aucun tutoiement dans ta réponse. Et merci encore une fois. :)

Comment: @Oreste Faistes comme you pensezs le mieux pour you être à l'aise dans l'échange :-). Perso, j'ai une lourde tendance à tutoyer, mais je respecte les vouvoyeurses et bascule ipso statim, même si c'est difficile. Après, je passe les 2/3 de mon temps pro à youyoyer… :-) Cordialement

Answer (score 2):

Il est habituel de ne pas utiliser d'article dans ce contexte, mais l'utiliser ne résulte pas en une faute; si ce n'est pas usuel, il n'y a quand même pas de principe contradictoire qui empêche d'utiliser l'article. En fait de nombreux cas d'utilisation de l'article se trouvent  dans la littérature.

Les noms associés à cet usage, noms de métier ou noms assimilés à des noms de métiers, sont les suivants : soldat, balayeur, écrivain, guide, cowboy, flic, ingénieur, archéologue, ouvrier, artisan, coureur de vitesse, acteur tragique, berger, directeur commercial, homme de lettres, travailleur, metteur en scène d'action, homme politique, poète, écrivain public, médecin.

On ne trouve des exemples que pour la première personne du singulier.

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=gU-JAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT2&dq=%22non+je+suis+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD0bD5tL7uAhWF3oUKHbWOATYQ6AEwAHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22non%20je%20suis%20un%22&f=false)) Mais non : je suis un Soldat. Chargé, entraîné, conditionné depuis l'enfance pour la défense de Ter, mon pays.

([réf;](https://books.google.fr/books?id=xSALBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&dq=%22non+je+suis+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD0bD5tL7uAhWF3oUKHbWOATYQ6AEwD3oECC8QAg#v=onepage&q=%22non%20je%20suis%20un%22&f=false)) Euh non, je suis un balayeur plutôt. Je suis un balayeur magicien, euh, un magicien balayeur.

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=_E9d43aoickC&pg=PP44&dq=%22non+je+suis+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD0bD5tL7uAhWF3oUKHbWOATYQ6AEwE3oECDcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22non%20je%20suis%20un%22&f=false)) " Bien sûr que non . Je suis un écrivain . J'arrange les choses , je les embellis .

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eQ1hqHzSMnwC&pg=PA464&dq=%22non+je+suis+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD0bD5tL7uAhWF3oUKHbWOATYQ6AEwGHoECD4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22non%20je%20suis%20un%22&f=false))   « Ca alors, je te vois ! Mais tu n'es pas sous forme de corps spirituel ? -Non, je suis un guide ...

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=X2ZZBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT106&dq=%22non+je+suis+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD0bD5tL7uAhWF3oUKHbWOATYQ6AEwGnoECEEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22non%20je%20suis%20un%22&f=false)) — Vous dealez de la drogue, Ach ? — Non, je suis un cowboy, un genre de shérif, répondit Acheron en démarrant.

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=EX0cBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT49&dq=%22non+je+suis+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD0bD5tL7uAhWF3oUKHbWOATYQ6AEwG3oECEUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22non%20je%20suis%20un%22&f=false)) Non, je suis un flic. Ou du moins c'est ce que je serais si on me laissait faire mon métier. »

([réf](https://books.google.fr/books?id=eWGJAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT313&dq=%22non+je+suis+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD0bD5tL7uAhWF3oUKHbWOATYQ6AEwV3oECBIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22non%20je%20suis%20un%22&f=false)) Non, je suis un ingénieur, pas un archéologue. Je vous laisse volontiers toute la gloire et la célébrité.

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=mOFdAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT303&dq=%22non+je+suis+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD0bD5tL7uAhWF3oUKHbWOATYQ6AEwWHoECCcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22non%20je%20suis%20un%22&f=false))  Non, je suis un prêtre diocésain, mais je peux dire la messe en latin.

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=_9oYCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22je+suis+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiz8sKzu77uAhWR0eAKHfYcDM4Q6AEwAXoECE4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22je%20suis%20un%22&f=false)) Je ne suis pas forcément ce que j'écris. Mais j'écris. Ça, je le suis. Je suis un écrivain. C'est joli, au village ? Oui.

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=hATvPAAACAAJ&dq=%22je+suis+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiz8sKzu77uAhWR0eAKHfYcDM4Q6AEwNnoECGIQAQ)) Je suis un écrivain: guide de l'auteur professionnel

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=uAlBAQAAIAAJ&q=%22je+suis+un%22&dq=%22je+suis+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8h6CUvr7uAhVRExoKHUjcBrY4yAEQ6AEwAXoECE0QAg)) Je suis mécanicien , je suis un ouvrier , pas plus . - Je le suis aussi , dit Bernier .

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=JpZNAQAAIAAJ&q=%22je+suis+un%22&dq=%22je+suis+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8h6CUvr7uAhVRExoKHUjcBrY4yAEQ6AEwMnoECFwQAg))  j'aide Simenon à lutter contre ses doutes, ses remords, à repousser tous les spectres qui encombrent sa vie. « Je suis un artisan »

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=FLqxk81W7fgC&pg=PT12&dq=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDjYLswr7uAhVmyoUKHcnVC0wQ6AEwHHoECEUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22je%20suis%20devenu%20un%22&f=false))  Comment je suis devenu un flic.

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=4c26KO_-acQC&pg=PA20&dq=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDjYLswr7uAhVmyoUKHcnVC0wQ6AEwJHoECFAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22je%20suis%20devenu%20un%22&f=false)) Peu à peu, sur le plan sportif, j'ai émergé du lot et je suis devenu un coureur de vitesse. C'était un refuge, qui me permettait d'être accepté par les autres. J'allais faire des championnats qui me rapportaient, avec la victoire, des titres et

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=QUdFoIlIPzwC&pg=PT87&dq=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDjYLswr7uAhVmyoUKHcnVC0wQ6AEwJXoECFIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22je%20suis%20devenu%20un%22&f=false)) Moi, je ne voulais pas faire du « boulevard », entout cas pas que, alors je suis devenu un acteur tragique.

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=LcIFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA7&dq=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDjYLswr7uAhVmyoUKHcnVC0wQ6AEwNHoECFMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22je%20suis%20devenu%20un%22&f=false))   je suis devenu un Berger

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8DMZxAvUJaEC&pg=PT96&dq=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDjYLswr7uAhVmyoUKHcnVC0wQ6AEwOHoECEYQAg#v=onepage&q=%22je%20suis%20devenu%20un%22&f=false)) Et comble du comble, je suis devenu un commercial. Un directeur commercial.

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=gJvTaK99nwkC&pg=PT9&dq=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjo5fmrxr7uAhVpxoUKHZTZDIg4ZBDoATApegQISBAC#v=onepage&q=%22je%20suis%20devenu%20un%22&f=false)) à l'aune  de ce que je suis devenu: un écrivain,un type qui revient sur ses pas,

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Bcb_rwEytEIC&pg=PT113&dq=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjo5fmrxr7uAhVpxoUKHZTZDIg4ZBDoATAtegQITxAC#v=onepage&q=%22je%20suis%20devenu%20un%22&f=false)) Je suis devenu un homme de lettres. » Léon ne manie pas la langue de Bloy. L'exaspération de son style,

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=GU3jAAAAMAAJ&q=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&dq=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW3vuByb7uAhUNxIUKHdPYBIw4rAIQ6AEwAXoECEwQAg)) je suis devenu un homme quand je suis devenu un travailleur ,

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=IXxZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&dq=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW3vuByb7uAhUNxIUKHdPYBIw4rAIQ6AEwAnoECF0QAg)) Je suis devenu un metteur en scène d'action par accident ; c'est une absurdité . Je ne connais pas d'escrocs . . . je veux dire que je ne les connais pas en tant qu ' escrocs

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=EfvxAAAAMAAJ&q=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&dq=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW3vuByb7uAhUNxIUKHdPYBIw4rAIQ6AEwCnoECCIQAQ)) Bref de dire comment, mol qui n'ai même pas le certificat d'études primaires, je suis devenu un écrivain.

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=n5oQAAAAYAAJ&q=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&dq=%22je+suis+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiW3vuByb7uAhUNxIUKHdPYBIw4rAIQ6AEwD3oECC8QAg)) Je ne prends pas cela très au sérieux . time car après tout , si je suis devenu un homme politique : C'est une manière de parler

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=7vsaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP339&dq=%22il+est+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjui6m9zb7uAhVP9IUKHSKQAG0Q6AEwG3oECFIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22il%20est%20devenu%20un%22&f=false)) car il serait devenu un bon peintre avec la nature pour modèle , comme il est devenu un poète en faisant de la

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=7sVfVHBd7tYC&pg=PA34&dq=%22il+est+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-vJn6zr7uAhXB3oUKHaQoAuQ4ZBDoATAVegQIKRAC#v=onepage&q=%22il%20est%20devenu%20un%22&f=false)) 'estrade: elle incarne cette figure que l'écrivain rencontre partout où il va lorsqu'il est devenu... un écrivain public.

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=M1piAAAAMAAJ&q=%22il+est+devenu+un%22&dq=%22il+est+devenu+un%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwihg8Cf0L7uAhUInhQKHcS0BtE4yAEQ6AEwRHoECCkQAg)) Ainsi , à la limite , Paul n ' est plus médecin , mais - sans contradiction - il est resté un médecin ; ou encore , Paul était déjà médecin , mais c ' est maintenant qu ' il est devenu un médecin .

Comment: Merci beaucoup, j'ai l'impression qu'en cas d'opposition (_non, je ne suis pas ceci mais cela_) il est préférable de mettre l'article.

Comment: @Oreste Je ne crois que  votre impression sois conforme à l'usage ; je n'ai, personnellement pas du tout cette impression ; dans un cas comme le suivant, oui,  l'article est peut-être préférable  (mais, bien sûr, ce n'est plus tout à fait le même problème) : _Vous êtes le docteur ? Non, je suis un infirmier_.