# Quelle tournure (avec ou sans un) est correcte: « Il est (un) étudiant en médecine. »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Laquelle des formulations présentées ci-après est correcte (avec ou sans un).

> Il est étudiant en médecine.

ou

> Il est un étudiant en médecine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Il est avocat" vs "C'est un avocat" ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16619/il-est-avocat-vs-cest-un-avocat) & [Article devant un nom de métier](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/44409/358)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seule la première est correcte; la seconde est un anglicisme non accepté (pour l'instant…). On utilise toujours "un" cependant pour la tournure suivante, qui est néanmoins entièrement équivalente du  point de vue sens.

- C'est un étudiant en médecine.

Comment: **Seule** la première est correcte, *seulement* est ambigu et pas très idiomatique ici. Le *pour l'instant* laisse supposer qu'une évolution de l'acceptabilité s'amorce, ce qui n'est pas le cas.

Comment: @jlliagre Ça veut dire « On en ajoute  dans le langage tous les jours, alors sait-on jamais si le tour de celui-là ne va pas arriver. » (petite remarque personnelle, pas plus).

Comment: Certains anglicismes peuvent se comprendre mais celui-là n'apporte rien. Je pense qu'il n'a vraiment aucune chance d'être adopté.