# 'Il est' vs 'C'est' before determiner and noun

Tags: pronoms

I gather that before a determiner and noun in French you should say 'c'est' rather than 'il est' or 'elle est'. But I occasionally read sentences like this from Wikipedia:

> Connu sous le nom de 'E. T. A. Hoffmann', il est l'auteur de nombreux contes.

I am wondering why 'il est' rather than 'c'est' here?

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6317/1893

Answer (score 1):

Une explication de cet usage du présentatif « c'est » se trouve dans la grammaire suivante : [Kalmbach, Guide de grammaire française pour étudiants finnophones](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/IL-CA.html#2734).

> Quand le nom attribut du sujet indique la **profession** de quelqu’un, ce nom devient un **adjectif**. Il n’a donc pas de déterminant (le, ce, mon…) et on utilise la construction habituelle avec un adjectif « *il/elle est médecin* » comme « *il/elle est sympathique* ».
>
> À la question « *Quelle est la profession de…?* », on répond « *Il est…* », « *Elle est…* ».
>
> À la question « *Qui est-ce que c’est ?*», on répond par « *C’est + GN* », comme si on répondait à la question « *Qu’est-ce que c’est ?*».
>
> - Qu’est-ce que c’est ? C’est une planche à roulettes.
> - Qu’est-ce que c’est ? C’est un bouleau.
> - Qu’est-ce que c’est ? Ce sont des cadeaux pour mes enfants.
> - Qui est-ce que c’est ? C’est mon frère.
> - Qui c’est ? C’est un médecin.
>
> Si par exemple dans un hôpital on voit une personne habillée en blanc et qu’on ne sait pas si c’est une infirmière ou une médecin, on demanderait en français  « C’est une médecin ou une infirmière ? » et non pas « Quelle est la profession de cette femme en blanc ? ».
>
> L’inverse n’est pas vrai : à la question « *Quelle est sa profession?* » on peut répondre en utilisant « *c’est + déterminant + nom (GN)* ».
>
> - Quelle est la profession de ce monsieur ?
>   Il est tapissier-décorateur.
>   C’est un tapissier-décorateur.

It follows that before a determiner and noun in French you should say 'c'est' rather than 'il est' or 'elle est' in those cases when the question 'Qui est-ce ? 'or 'Qu'est-ce que c'est ?' can be asked. In the sentence in question there is no such question implied; so the use of the pronoun 'il' might still be possible. From the same reference more can be found about this problem. What is shown in the end is that '*c'est*' is not a possibility; this is so because the mentioning of the quality  of this person ('auteur de ombreux contes') is a matter of *qualification*, not one of *definition*.

> « *Il est* » + nom
>
> On peut utiliser « *IL est* » suivi d’un attribut groupe nominal, quand le pronom « IL » renvoie clairement à un nom qui a déjà été défini ou mentionné. Si on qualifie un nom déjà défini antérieurement (il a été mentionné), on y renvoie avec « il », qui est alors dans sa fonction normale de pronom anaphorique :
>
> ■ Qui est M. Martin ? – C’est un prof. Il était notre prof de français.
> ■ L’article se contracte également avec les prépositions de ou à quand elles sont un élément d’une locution prépositionnelle.
> ■ Garde ces photos pour toi, elles sont tout ce qui te reste de mes grands-parents.
> ■ C’est vers 2 ans que l’enfant prend conscience de son sexe. Vous lui dites qu’il est un garçon, ou une fille, vous lui expliquez la différence entre papa et maman.
>
> C’est ce qui explique l’opposition entre définition dans (a) et qualification (b) dans les exemples suivants :
>
> **(a)** En effet, le thème n’est pas toujours le sujet grammatical du verbe de la phrase. Cela peut être par exemple un complément de phrase.
> **(b)** Le nom peut être le sujet de la phrase. Il peut aussi être le complément direct du verbe ou un complément de phrase.
>
> Dans l’exemple (a), on dit que différentes choses peuvent être le thème : le sujet du verbe ou un complément de phrase, et on précise ce qui est par exemple le thème : Qu’est-ce qui est le thème ? (définition). Dans l’exemple (b), on parle du nom (qui est donc identifié), et on indique qu’il peut avoir plusieurs qualités : sujet, complément de verbe, complément de phrase.
>
> La différence peut parfois être très difficile à comprendre, parce qu’il faut savoir interpréter le sens précis des mots (et des constructions) pour choisir entre « *c’est* » et « *il est* » et, donc, avoir des connaissances en vocabulaire suffisamment étendues. En cas de doute, une solution est d’utiliser un autre verbe ou une autre construction :
>
> Le thème n’est pas toujours le sujet grammatical du verbe de la phrase. Un complément de phrase peut aussi être le sujet.
> ■ Le nom peut être le sujet de la phrase. Mais on peut aussi l’utiliser comme complément direct du verbe ou un complément de phrase. / Mais sa fonction peut aussi être celle de complément direct du verbe ou un complément de phrase.
> ■ L’article se contracte également avec les prépositions de ou à quand ces prépositions sont un élément d’une préposition composée. Etc.

- Connu sous le nom de 'E. T. A. Hoffmann', il est l'auteur de nombreux contes. (*Une qualité parmi d'autres possibles*)
- Connu sous le nom de 'E. T. A. Hoffmann', c'est l'auteur le plus lu pendant la période qui nous concerne. (*Qui est le plus lu ? Cest Hoffman.* définition)

At times it might be difficult to draw a line between the two, as the explanation says.

Comment: From my uneducated perspective, I see it as using "c'est" only when an obvious, more solid subject is referenced. In the last example, "l'auteur" is the subject of the main idea of the sentence (both "connu" and "c'est" refer to it, and perhaps "qui"), but in the example before that, it isn't, so a more definite "il" is required.  Is that an appropriate way of looking at it?

Comment: @RayButterworth ("Qui", relative pronoun, has for antecedent the word "période", nothing to do with "auteur"); I don't think that the idea of "more or less solid subject" is relevant at all; this would be solidity of the subject is relative only to the perception of the reader, as from the point of view of grammar either there exists a subject or there is none at all. I can't identify this case of a "weak subject" eliciting the use of "il". Also, "subject of the main idea" is not a term I can identify.

Comment: Étonnant de la part de Kalmbach. Je n'ai jamais entendu personne demander **Qui est-ce que c'est ?** Les très rares occurrences que trouvent les moteurs de recherche semblent toutes provenir de non francophones.

Comment: @jlliagre Il ne me semble pas non plus avoir lu ça, ni l'avoir entendu ; cependant, c'est un cas de construction standard. On doit pouvoir dire « Qui est-ce que vous voyez ? », même si « Qui vous voyez ? » est la forme courante ; le présentatif « il y a », de même, devrait pouvoir s'utiliser en parallèle avec « Qu'est-ce qu'il y a ? », qui est une forme courante. « Qui est-ce qu'il y a ? », même si c'est une question peu utilisée ou pas du tout, me semble en fait assez naturelle, je ne m'interroge pas d'emblé sur sa validité comme dans le cas de « Qui est-ce que c'est ? ». (1/2)

Comment: @jlliagre  La  restriction aux choses du seul fait de la rare utilisation me parait arbitraire. À mon avis, le locuteur doit pouvoir identifier la logique d'une construction et ne pas laisser l'habitude dicter un usage de délimitation étroite (moins de règles difficiles à justifier, plus de liberté). (2/2)

Comment: La forme la plus courante est ***Vous voyez qui ?*** Je ne dis pas que la phrase est strictement incorrecte mais je maintiens que personne ne dit *Qui est-ce que c'est ?* et qu'une grammaire doit s'appuyer sur des phrases réelles ou du moins plausibles, pas sur des formes défectives. Au contraire, *Pour qui est-ce que c'est ?* est un exemple de ce que les gens peuvent dire, encore que ce sera plus souvent *C'est pour qui ?*

Comment: @jlliagre Tu as raison, personne ne dit vraiment _qui est-ce que c'est?_, peut-être les enfants quand ils apprennent, et encore, ils passent très vite à _c'est qui?_. _Qui vous voyez?_ ne se rencontre pas non plus. Et je suis tout à fait d'accord, avec toi et avec LBU, qui dans l'introduction de la 12e édition, parle d'observer d'abord la langue réelle, puis de modérer les jugements normatifs ...