# when can there be an article after a pronoun + être?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, articles

I thought [*pronoun*] + [*être*] could never be followed by an article:

- ✅ je suis dentiste ❌ je suis *un* dentiste
- ✅ elle est sénégalaise ❌ elle est *une* Sénégalaise

but I’ve been been told you can say « tu es un bon ami », which has absolutely thrown me off and I cannot come up with a comprehensive mental model that accommodates this possibility. What even are the rules? I feel completely lost.

1. What’s the difference between « tu es un bon ami » and « elle est une bonne amie » that makes the former okay and the latter not? They’re both [*pronoun*] + [*être*] + [*article*] + [*noun*].
2. I thought nationalities, jobs, etc. appeared as [*pronoun*] + [*être*] + [*title WITHOUT article*]? What’s with « c’est un boulanger »?
3. All in all, if I had a sentence I wanted to translate into French, what questions should I ask myself to determine what the right pronoun is, and whether to include an article or not?

Comment: Both "je suis un dentiste" and "je suis une Sénégalaise" seem perfectly acceptable to me (the version without article sounds posher but not necessarily more common in everyday speech, at least where I live). It's only in the third person that they sound off, probably because the version with "c'est" exists and would be used over "il est" or "elle est" in almost all contexts except formal writing

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6317/1893

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You write "[pronoun] + [être] could never be followed by an article". That's too simplified to be applied like that.
*Je suis dentiste* but *je suis un bon dentiste* (not mandatory to have the indefinite article but we would usually have it).
When you say *je suis sénégalaise*, *sénégalaise* is definitely an adjective, not a noun. When you say *je suis dentiste*/*je suis boulanger* the profession here works as an adjective and we do not have an article.

From what you are writing it seems you are confused about different sorts of pronouns.
*Tu es un bon ami* and *tu es une bonne amie* are both perfectly fine. So are
*c'est un bon ami* and  *c'est une bonne amie*.
When you write that *tu es un bon ami* and *elle est une bonne amie* are both [pronoun] + [être] + [article] + [noun] you are missing an essential point: *tu* is a 2nd person and *il/elle* is a 3rd person. And French has the gallicism ***c'est*** (***ce sont***) where the demonstrative pronoun *ce (c')* can in lots of cases replace the 3rd person subject personal pronouns.
I would not say that *elle est une bonne amie* is wrong, it is just that it is not usual to say it like that, if I read it I know at once the person writing it is not a French native.  It is only with nationalities, professions and religions that using the personal pronoun or the demonstrative pronoun makes no difference at all.

And using the personal pronouns (*il(s), elle(s)*) or the demonstrative pronoun, makes a difference in construction:

- *c’est* / *ce sont* + (*un/une/de*) + noun
- *il / elle est* (no article) + noun

**Edit:**
To answer the questions in [the comments](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/when-can-there-be-an-article-after-a-pronoun-%C3%AAtre/54026?noredirect=1#comment115180_54026): "why is it *une dentiste canadienne/politicienne sénégalaise* but *professeur d’histoire/étudiante en droit* ?

*Je suis dentiste, je suis professeur, elle est professeure d'histoire*, *elle est étudiante en droit* etc...:  the info you want to give is the just about the job/occupation.  When you say *je suis une dentiste canadienne*, the info you want to give is that you're not just any *dentiste*, you're *canadienne*; *je suis une étudiante en droit allemande* → the info you want to give is that you're not just any *étudiante en droit*, you're *allemande* (one particular student among all law students). When you say *je suis étudiante en droit à Paris II*,  *Paris II* is not a personal info, it just tells about the place of study. *Je suis une étudiante allemande qui suit des cours à Paris II* (*Je suis une étudiante allemande et je suis des cours à Paris II*).

Comment: would i be correct in thinking that the rules then are [as shown here](https://rentry.co/bhvo7)?

Comment: @Min that's correct.

Comment: what about [these](https://rentry.co/9hx56)?

Comment: @Min I'd rather say: *je suis une dentiste canadienne*, *c'est une politicienne sénégalaise*

Comment: do you mind moving the convo over to: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/54040/33269 – i’d appreciate it if you could please elaborate why it’s ‘une dentiste canadienne/politicienne sénégalaise’ but ‘professeur d’histoire/étudiantes en droit’ is fine in more detail please?

Comment: @Min It's still the same question. *Je suis dentiste*,  *je suis professeur*, *elle est dentiste*, *elle est professeur* etc... You add the article when you use an adjective to define the job. *Je suis une dentiste canadienne*, *c'est une politicienne sénégalaise*. When you say *je suis professeur d'histoire*, *je suis étudiante en droit*, the job/occupation is *professeur d'histoire*, *étudiante en droit*, no  adjective. Compare with *je suis une professeur d'histoire canadienne*, *je suis une étudiante en droit allemande*.

Comment: so an additional adjective is what causes there to be an article? so no article in « *elle est étudiante en droit à l’université de [name]* », but as soon as i add an adjective it should be « *c’est **une** bonne étudiante en droit à l’université de [name]* »?

Comment: @Min Please see answer above: with *c'est* you always have the indefinite article.  *je suis une étudiante en droit* → the info you want to give is the occupation. *je suis une étudiante en droit allemande* → the info you want to give that you're not just any *étudiante en droit*, you're *allemande* (one particular student among all law students)

Comment: still confused *exactly when* i can no longer stick to [*pronoun*] + [*être*] + [*adjectival **without** an article*] and HAVE to switch to [*je/tu/vous*] + [*être*] + ***un(e)*** + [*NP*] or c’est/ce sont + ***un(e)*** + [*NP*]. is ‘a law student at X university’ generic enough to appear without *un(e)* or not? where exactly do you draw the line?

Comment: a student, a law student, a law student at X uni, a law student at X uni from Germany, a smart law student at X uni from Germany… a farmer, a chicken farmer, a free-range chicken farmer, … when does it stop being generic and start being specific enough to warrant the definite article?

Comment: @Min All those can't compare and it goes way beyond the French language. In "a free-range chicken farmer", free-range applies to the chicken, not to the farmer!  Plus words are used in complete sentences, as said before the grammatical subject matters.  // "A farmer" →  *un fermier* but "a chicken farmer" → un *éleveur de poulets*, but I expect most of them would say *j'élève des poulets* when defining their job.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding:

- <strike>The article is never wrong, just less idiomatic when it's not necessary.</strike> The article is usually heard as wrong in the case of a subject clitic pronoun and an unmodified attribute, if I read the comments right.
- Most modification of the noun triggers needing the article. I say "most" because I have a vague sense that if you had a compound noun or a noun + adjective of a certain class (e.g. *politicienne sénégalaise*) it might still be acceptable to drop the article.
- With "ce" instead of a regular subject pronoun the article is required. *C'est un dentiste.*

Comment: Hmmm _elle est une Sénégalaise_ ne se dit pas, à mon avis.

Comment: @Frank That is, outright wrong, not just less than ideal?

Comment: I think so. Curiously, _c'est une Sénégalaise_ seems to work, but not _elle est une Sénégalaise_. Similarly, if we tried _il est un Français_, it feels like _there is a French man..._ and one is waiting for details or a story, maybe. I'd be curious to hear how other native French speaker feel here.

Comment: That's because *elle est* entails a predicative adjective (*adjectif attribut*), therefore *elle est sénégalaise* (adjective with lower case).  But  *c'est une Sénégalaise* (noun with upper case) because after *c'est*  we have a noun. In *une politicienne sénégalaise* the noun is politicienne and *sénégalaise* is the attribute adjective (*adjectif épithète*) that defines *politicienne*.

Comment: @None Yeap, completely agreed :-)

Comment: Without a liaison between *elle* and *est*, I think the following sentence is just fine: *Lui est un Français de Paris, elle est une Sénégalaise de Dakar*. Of course, the second *est* can be dropped.

Comment: @jlliagre Mais bon, à l'oral, on aurait tendance à dire _lui, c'est un Français de Paris, et elle une Sénégalaise de Dakar_, à mon avis.

Comment: @Frank Oui, bien sûr. Ce que je voulais dire, c'est que *Lui est un Français* ne choque pas l'oreille comme le fait *Il est un français* et qu'un *elle* tonique peut passer dans le même contexte. Ce n'est pas le cas de *moi* ou *toi* qui imposent la reprise d'un pronom atone : **Moi suis un Français, *toi es un Belge* -> *Moi, je suis un Français, toi, tu es un Belge*.