# pronoun + être + article or no article?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, articles

am i correct in thinking that the rules on when to include an article or not are:

- je/tu/vous + être

  - title (objective; a job/nationality/etc) or adjective → NO article

    - je suis dentiste canadienne
    - tu es professeur d’histoire
    - vous êtes très intelligent
  - description → ARTICLE + noun phrase

    - je suis une bonne dentiste canadienne
    - tu es un bon ami
- il(s)/elle(s) → adjective/title (NO article)

  - elle est politicienne sénégalaise
  - elles sont étudiantes en droit
  - ils sont américains
- c’est/ce sont + ARTICLE + noun phrase

  - c’est mon cousin
  - c’est un professeur d’histoire
  - ce sont mes amies françaises

in addition, i’d appreciate it if you could come up with short **nontrivial** sentences that fall under each category, please!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [when can there be an article after a pronoun + être?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/when-can-there-be-an-article-after-a-pronoun-%c3%aatre)

Answer (score 0):

❌ Je suis dentiste canadienne  → ✅ Je suis une dentiste canadienne / ✅ Je suis dentiste et canadienne
✅ Tu es professeur d’histoire (= ✅ Tu es un professeur d’histoire)
✅ Vous êtes très intelligent
✅ Je suis une bonne dentiste canadienne
✅ Tu es un bon ami

❌ Elle est politicienne sénégalaise  → ✅ C'est un politicienne sénégalaise
✅ Elles sont étudiantes en droit (= ✅ Ce sont des étudiantes en droit )
✅ Ils sont américains

✅ C’est mon cousin
✅ C’est un professeur d’histoire
✅ Ce sont mes amies françaises

Comment: why? what’s the thing that causes there to be the indefinite article? an additional adjective? so no article in « *elle est étudiante en droit à l’université de [name]* », but as soon as i add an adjective it should be « *c’est **une** bonne étudiante en droit à l’université de [name]* »?

Comment: @Min You've already asked the [same question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/when-can-there-be-an-article-after-a-pronoun-%c3%aatre/54026?noredirect=1#comment115184_54026).