Quelle est la différence entre «le livre, il est sur l'étagère» et «le livre, c'est sur l'étagère»?
Dans d'autres cas, on peut choisir entre il est et c'est selon le complément du verbe être comme ça:

Le livre, il est amusant.
Le livre, c'est un roman.
Le livre, c'est un roman amusant.

De même, on peut décider selon le référent si le verbe est suivi d'un syntagme prépositionnel:

L'homme, il est dans la chambre.
L'homme, c'est dans la chambre. X

Mais si le référent est inanimé, les deux pronoms sont possibles:

Le livre, il est sur l'étagère.
Le livre, c'est sur l'étagère.

J'imagine donc qu'il y a une différence de sens entre (6) et (7), peut-être qu'on traduirait (6) en anglais comme «it is on the shelf» et (7) comme «this/that is on the shelf». Est-ce exact? Ou quelle est la différence?

1 2, 4, 6, [Le livre | L'homme]  est … — 3,  5, 7 : [ Ce livre | Cet homme] est…

https://french.stackexchange.com/q/6317/1893

Toutes ces phrases ne peuvent pas être prises sans contexte. Le livre que tu m'as offert, il est amusant. Ce livre (ou le livre qu'on m'a offert)  c'est un roman (amusant). L'homme (dont je viens de parler), il est dans sa chambre. L'homme, c'est dans la chambre que je l'ai vu. Le livre (dont je viens de parler) il est sur l'étagère. Le livre ? C'est sur l'étagère que tu dois le poser.

Par contre je pourrais dire La femme c'est l'avenir de l'homme (femme étant ici ne pas une femme en particulier, c'est la femme en général). Le livre c'est mieux que les écrans (je parle des livres en général, pas d'un livre en particulier).

Pour être bref, la différence entre les 2 c'est que dans  « le livre il est sur l'étagère » il représente  le livre et dans « le livre, c'est sur l'étagère », c' se réfère à autre chose (un lieu ici). Même chose pour l'homme, il est/c'est dans la chambre. Je pense que la question est mal posée parce que tu donnes des phrases sans contextes et tu pars de l'a priori que L'homme, c'est dans la chambre serait possible et que Le livre, c'est sur l'étagère le serait.

@None Désolé pour la confusion, mais (5) n'est pas possible dans ma question, donc il y a un X.

Mais pourquoi est-ce que tu dis que ce n'est pas possible, il faut que tu donnes le contexte de tes phrases car autant 5 que 7 sont possibles selon le contexte ? Ce sont les mêmes raisons qui font que 5 et 7 sont possibles ou pas possible. Ce n'est pas une question de référent animé ou inanimé mais la fonction de "c'".

Le livre, il est sur l'étagère. est une dislocation, un redoublement du sujet considéré comme populaire dans le passé mais devenu extrêmement courant aujourd'hui. Voir par exemple cette question ou cette video (Houlala le train, il est en train de partir !).
La forme avec c'est est beaucoup plus rare et inattendue au moins en France, un pronom indéfini s'accordant mal avec un sujet bien défini, mais le sens peut être similaire (le livre, c'est sur l'étagère [qu'il est]) ou correspondre à l'un des sens plus courants quand livre est au pluriel :

Les livres, c'est sur l'étagère.

C'est à dire :

Les livres, c'est sur l'étagère [qu'on les trouve].

ou

Les livres, c'est sur l'étagère [qu'on les met].

Comme toujours, le contexte est primordial pour déterminer le sens précis d'une phrase.

Et oui contexte, contexte.... c'est ce qui fait défaut dans la question qui est trop vague, on peut faire des scénarios à l'infini. Range mieux tes affaires, le livre c'est sur l'étagère, le pull c'est dans l'armoire, et  pas le contraire.

Il n'y a pas vraiment de différence de sens. Mais aucune de ces tournures n'est très correcte, bien qu'elles soient parfois entendues. Le problème est la répétition du sujet. Il vaut mieux simplifier, et ne pas répéter le sujet, bien que cela arrive dans des contextes oraux en particulier. A mon avis, le plus commun serait: Le livre? Il est sur l'étagère, en séparant deux phrases. (5) et (7) sont les plus douteuses.

Les phrases sont ainsi pour être concis. L'idée est simplement qu'on sait le référent parce qu'il est prononcé récemment. (Mais quand même, la répétition telle quelle est bien courante où moi je reste, et elle devrait être courante partout lorsqu'on met l'accent sur le sujet.)

@joshisanonymous Tu es où? En France métropolitaine, les phrases ci-dessus passent très difficilement.

Louisiane, mais comme j'ai dit, avec l'accent sur le sujet, je ne pense pas que la répétition serait étrange n'importe où. En effet, voici un exemple où le MANQUE de répétition est l'étrange: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-genre-des-villes-paris-rome-etc-gender-of-towns-and-cities.592559/post-3314016
