# When to use “il est tard” vs “c'est tard”?

Tags: pronoms, indications-de-temps, pronoms-impersonnels

Could you guys tell me if there is any difference between the following:

> Il est tard. On y va!
>   C'est tard. On y va!

If so, does it apply also to:

> Il est lundi (aujourd'hui).
>   C'est lundi (aujourd'hui).
>   On est lundi (aujourd'hui).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Time of the day and days of the week do not work the same way:

Time of the day:

- *Il est tard. On y va !* means that we'd better go as it is late and we are running late. - *Il est* applies to the time it is now and this is perfectly correct.
- *C'est tard. On y va !* sounds strange. Concerning the time of the day *C'est* is not expected to apply to the time it is now but to the happening of an event at a given time. For example: *Il n'arrivera que lundi prochain ? C'est tard !* is fine. And in this last case *Il est tard* wouldn't work.
- Similarly, *Il est 8 heures* is correct and *C'est 8 heures* is not. But *C'est à 8 heures*, applied to the happening of an event, is perfectly correct.
- But *On y va ? - C'est tard, c'était il y a une heure qu'il fallait y aller !* works though. In this case, *c'est* applies to the event *on y va maintenant* and not to the time it is now. This is why it works. *On y va ? - Il est tard, c'était il y a une heure qu'il fallait y aller !* would have worked as well: instead of referring to the event *on y va maintenant* we would be referring to the time it is now. The meaning would be the same.

Days of the week:

- *On est lundi* and *C'est lundi* are both correct and mean exactly the same thing: today is Monday.
- *Il est lundi* is incorrect.
- Concerning the happening of an event, *c'est* is fine: *N'oublie pas qu'il faut se préparer pour cet événement ! Or c'est lundi prochain.*

Comment: *C'est 8 heures* (and *Ca fait 8 heures*) is a regionalism used in Savoie, Suisse romande, and Belgium too I think.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon, I don't remember having heard _c'est 8 heures_ for _il est 8 heures_ in Belgium.

Comment: @Unfrancophone Then it's only a *romandisme*...

Answer (score 4):

In usual -but not bad- language,you could use both, but in order to be precise it depends if you have knowledge of the time when you say the sentence.

You have time on mind: *Il est tard* on y va. is a more pragmatic sentence.

You take knowledge of the time at the moment: *C'est tard on y va.* could be said.

Something is pointed by the "C'" (an object) on this case this is the time.
The correct but a bit more valuable sentence in all case is more *Il est tard*
But in order to be more pleasant like on a night event ending: *C'est tard on y va* is more appropriate as I use it.

*Il est lundi (aujourd'hui).
C'est lundi (aujourd'hui).
On est lundi (aujourd'hui).*

Are really the same, without any language level sort.

As i see it:

- Usual & multi-usages: *Il est lundi*

-*C'est lundi* : More used in the north, it depends.

-*On est lundi* Probably the best to say in the south where the singing accent can be heard.

Answer (score 3):

*Il est tard*, *C'est tard*, even *Il se fait tard,* are all synonyms, and the only difference is the language level (*Il se fait tard* being the most formal one).

As for your second question, both *C'est lundi* and *On est lundi* are correct. *Il est lundi* is not.

Comment: Could you show me the slight differences, if any, between those expressions? I really don't get why "c'est tard" is correct and "c'est lundi" isn't.

Comment: In my opinion, there's absolutely no difference between *Il est tard/lundi* and *C'est tard/lundi*. And *C'est lundi* **is** correct.

Comment: Oh ok, I misread your answer. What you said was that "il est lundi" is not correct. That's what I wanted to ask you :)

Comment: It just doesn't sound right :)

Comment: @RickyRobinson I wouldn't say “c'est tard, on y va”, only “il est tard, on y va” or “il se fait tard, allons-y” (slightly more formal register). “C'est tard” in this sense sounds weird to my ears (mostly Parisian and thereabouts).