# When do you use C'est vs ce sont ?

Tags: grammaire

I am working on an assignment and can't figure out which sentence is correct...

> C’est de longs devoirs laborieux
>
> Ce sont de longs devoirs laborieux

Could somebody please tell me which is correct (if any are) and why?

Answer (score 2):

> Ce sont de longs devoirs laborieux

I'm guessing that your question isn't about the conjugation (*est* being 3rd-person singular, *sont* being plural) but about whether the subject of the verb is *ce* (singular) or *de longs devoirs* (plural).

The answer is that in this [« tour présentatif »](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/6227), you treat the thing you're talking about as the subject of the verb, even though grammatically you would expect *ce* to take that role.

Thus, *de longs devoirs* is your subject and you use *sont* to agree with the plural.

Comment: thank you so much!!

Comment: The singular can also be used, but it is more colloquial.

Comment: @MathieuBouville Ah, okay. (So for an assignment/test in a class, the asker should probably stick with *sont*.)

Comment: Like using 'there is' where you should use 'there are': it happens, but it shouldn't.

Comment: @MathieuBouville Sometimes, the singular is even mandatory for the verb even when referring to a plural: *Ce sont de longs devoirs laborieux. – Oui, c'en **est** !* (not *c'en sont*). Also: *Combien ça coûte ? – **C'est** huit euros par personne.* (not *ce sont huit euros*). ***C'est** vous qui voyez* (not *ce sont vous qui voyez*)

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on whether the subject is singular or plural, if you are talking about only one exercise that you find hard, you can just say:

> C’est un exercice laborieux.

But if you are talking about various exercises, we would rather use:

> Ce sont de longs devoirs laborieux.

Comment: The subject, being the pronoun *ce*, is technically singular, This is a case where the verb can agree with its object instead of its subject.